# dynamic array name to sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here val array are dynamic. it should sort by array name as alphabetically. results expected Managed,Non Managed, Non Managed.

```
var val=['NON MANAGED','MANAGED','NON MANAGED'];    
    var isManagedval=[];                
        isManagedval.push(val);
        isManagedval.sort(function(a,b) {return (a-b)});
        console.log(isManagedval);
```

Comment: please add the raw data and what you have tried. please have a look here: [mcve]

Comment: The isManagedVal becomes an array inside an array.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need?

```js
var val=['NON MANAGED','MANAGED','NON MANAGED'];
val.sort();

console.log(val);
```

Comment: no not like that NON MANAGED and Managed value will come dynamically that we need to push into array then we have to sort();

Comment: above which u mention is static sort . that we knew very well

Comment: @Jaykumar: Pardon me sir, I know my script is static. but your scripts is pretty equal with mind. Can you give me more specific what you need?